# How to guarantee that files downloaded via QNetworkAccessManager are not corrupted?

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming

I have been looking for an answer to this question, but not able to find it.

I am using the `QNetworkAccessManager` to download a file from a Web server and I want to make sure this file gets downloaded without any corruption.

I once implemented a checksum for each file, but this can get tedious and might be unnecessary. I previously just assumed corruption could happen with `QNetworkAccessManager`. 
A prerequisite is that the `QNetworkReply` object returned from a call to the `QNetworkAccessManager`'s method `get()` has issued the finished signal.

How can I make sure that the files downloaded from a web server via `QNetworkAccessManager` won't be corrupted?

Comment: What do you mean by "corrupted" file? Did you try the signal `error(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)`?

Comment: Sorry if my question was a bit unclear. Assume no error signal is emitted and the finished signal is emitted, is the downloaded file then guaranteed to be complete? (I am using the readyRead() signal to read the downloaded data)

Comment: No because the finished signal is always emitted, even if your download of the file was corrupted. I think you have to check the size of the file downloaded (see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#uploadProgress))

Comment: But if no error signal was emitted, could it still be corrupted?

Comment: I stumbled across this problem a while ago, I was downloading a file which in fact didn't exist... No error signal, but when I checked with [downloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived, qint64 bytesTotal)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#downloadProgress), *bytesTotal* was equal to -1..

Comment: I see. So I should check the download progress and only when bytes received equals bytes total I can say that the download was successful?

Comment: That's exactly the way I would do it :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience and knowledge about this issue. I will test it out and see how it works. I feel it's a bit strange this is not mentioned in the docs as mostly people want to download a non-corrupt file I would assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP/IP doesn't guarantee error-free transmission of data, so even if you got a file of correct size from `QNetworkAccessManager`, the file still can be corrupted. You need to use a hash that detects errors better than TCP/IP can. This has nothing to do with `QNetworkAccessManager` itself, your web browser suffers from the same problem: occasionally you'll get a corrupted download even if everything otherwise seems peachy.

Comment: Sounds reasonable and was what I previously assumed. So  I should still use a hash.